# How to validate a JSON post with Dingo API in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate a json I'm getting via post, using the Dingo API library in Laravel. It seems that the validation is working incorrectly as I send a valid JSON according to the fields I am validating and it returns me the message saying:

The X field is required.

But I'm sending the X field in json, which I do not understand.

JSON:

```
    [
      {
        "currency_id": 1,
        "bills": [
            {
                "barcode": "99999.9999999.99999999.9999 9",
                "due_date": "2018-09-14",
                "value": 70.00
            },
            {
                "barcode": "8888.888888.88888.8888 8",
                "due_date": "2018-09-15",
                "value": 32.00
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
"message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
"errors": {
    "currency_id": [
        "The currency id field is required."
    ],
    "bills": [
        "The bills field is required."
    ]
},
```

This is my custom FormRequest with validation rules, where I pass it as a parameter in the BillController store method.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Rules\Sum;
use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;


class BillRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'currency_id' => 'required|integer|exists:currency,id',
            'bills' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1', 'max:3', new Sum],
            'bills.*.barcode' => 'required|string|min:10|max:255',
            'bills.*.due_date' => 'date',
            'bills.*.value' => 'required|numeric|between:10,30000',
        ];
    }


}
```

Comment: make sure that the post request has this header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: your object resides within an array try `*.currency_id`

Comment: Thanks I was able to validate the currency_id field, but I could not validate the second bill field which is an array, how could I validate the array that is inside bills?

Comment: In fact no validation works, it goes straight from validation, even if I send an empty json

Comment: I managed to solve it, I'll post the answer of how it was.

Answer (score 1):

To solve I had to put *. in front of each rule, as I'm getting an array the validator only understands this way.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        '*.currency_id' => 'required|integer|exists:currency,id',
        '*.bills' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1', 'max:3', new Sum],
        '*.bills.*.barcode' => 'required|string|min:10|max:255',
        '*.bills.*.due_date' => 'date',
        '*.bills.*.value' => 'required|numeric|between:10,30000',
    ];
}
```